# Reference Resource @values/color/my_color.xml from android:color

Tags: android, xml, colors

I want to change the color of my custom pressed state for different version of android.

Example: v19 = white, v18 and lower = cyan blue

How do I reference @values/color/my_color as my button color.

Referencing default Android color values would be awesome, but I don't know how to do it :/

Here is my code

**button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid 
            android:color="@values/color/button_selection" /> //ERROR: SAYS RESOURCE DOESN'T EXIST, BUT IT DOES
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item 
    android:state_pressed="false" >
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

**color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="button_selection">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

If this is a duplicate, please point me to it.

Thank you

Comment: `@values/color/button_selection` does not exist. it is either `@values/button_selection` or `@color/button_selection`

Comment: @njzk2 Lol! Removing `@values` from `@values/color/button_selected` works great. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your colors.xml in res/values/ folder. Then you can reference it from your layouts like `@color/<attribute_name>`.

Example (res/values/colors.xml):

```
<resources>
    <color name="custom_black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Reference:

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/custom_black" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short - Remove `@values` from the reference

1. Place `color.xml` in the `values` folder of `res`
2. Reference `android:color="@color/my_custom_color"`.